# Why does my gun dog like gun shots but not fire works or thunder

Tags: dogs

I have a gun dog and she loves shooting, when she hears the shots it gives her a buzz and she gets excited, but with fire works and thunder she gets scared. How can she like gun shots but not the sound of thunder or fireworks?

Comment: If you take your dog hunting, then I'd say it's because the dog associates the gun shot with fun things. Nothing fun comes from fireworks or lightning. If you don't take your dog hunting, then I'm really at a loss too.

Comment: This question needs to be clarified as to the scenario where the dog is exposed to gun shots, as implied in the comment by @Kai